# Div with Text, inside a div

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to insert a div with text and a background inside of a container div.

The text div won't center nor be vertically centered.

The final result should look something like this
[image: Yes. A cat I know..]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcy6kew/)

For now I have this

```
<div id="landingimg">
    <div>
        <h1>Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!</h1>
    </div>
</div>

#landingimg {
    background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 960px;
    max-width:100%;
    height: 470px;
}

#landingimg div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#landingimg div {
    background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: add display: table-cell;  to  #landingimg div

Comment: Mate you are missing the angle bracket while closing the h1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center an element horizontally and vertically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461521/how-to-center-an-element-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: Actually the angle bracket is not the problem. You should firstly position div and then set its top. And thats it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcy6kew/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have incomplete CSS, as well as a couple errors both in your CSS and HTML. I put together a JSFiddle for you to view and use as a guide for correcting your problem and achieving what you need. My solution will take care of centering your inner div, as well as make that inner div `display: table;` and the h1 `display: table-cell`.

The reason for this is because you not only want to center your div text on the page, but you also want to center your text in your div (`h1`) both horizontally and vertically. The only way to center your text properly vertically in it's parent container is to use `display: table-cell;` along with `vertical-align: middle;`

You can view the JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lxpg4bxn/

**Your HTML should be the following:**

```
<div id="landingimg">
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>
      Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
    </h1>
    <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

And you should use the following CSS:

```
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
#landingimg{
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 960px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 470px;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
}
#landingimg div.inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: -50px 0 0 -200px;
  display: table;
}
#landingimg div.inner > h1{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Add this to inner div and Change Size according to need

```
 <div id="landingimg">
             <div class="innerDiv">
             <h1>
               Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
             </h1
                </div>
                </div>
```

> CSS

```
 .innerDiv{
        position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    width: 250px;
    height: 143px;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this article: [Centering in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

```css
#landingimg{
  background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 960px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 470px;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#landingimg div h1{

  text-align: center;
  
}
#landingimg div{
  background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
```

```html
           <div id="landingimg">
             <div class="child">
             <h1>
               Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
             </h1>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<img>` instead of `background-image`, then use positioning in CSS.

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
#landingimg{
  width: 960px;
  max-width:100%;
}

#landingimg div h1{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
}
#landingimg div{
  background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="landingimg">
   <div>
     <img src="https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg" alt="">
     <h1>
       Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
     </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try adding `magin: 0 auto;` to `#landingimg div`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code. I have added the main container `div` as **relative** and the inner `div` as **absolute** :

```css
#landingimg{
  background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 960px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 470px;
  position:relative;
}

#landingimg div h1{

  text-align: center;
  
}
#landingimg div{
  background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:70px;
  left:100px;
  }
```

```html
           <div id="landingimg">
             <div>
             <h1>
               Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
             </h1>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One more solution without absolute positioning:

```
#landingimg{
    background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 960px;
    max-width:100%;
    height: 470px;
    display: table;
    background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
}
#landingimg div h1{
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
#landingimg div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpcy6kew/8

Answer (score 0):

This worked based on some mathematical calculation with the `px`

```
<div id="landingimg">
     <div class="center">
         <h1>
           Velkommen til hele Danmarks Fristad!
         </h1
      </div>
</div>

#landingimg{
  background: url("https://www.icr.org/i/wide/cat_walking_wide.jpg") no-repeat;
  width: 960px;
  max-width:100%;
  height: 470px;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#landingimg div h1{

  text-align: center;

}
.center{
  background-color: rgba(43, 44, 44, 0.5);
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Adding the class isn't necessary.